# git repo objects directory balloons to large sizes for no apparent reason

Tags: git

I'm having an issue with git repositories suddenly ballooning to very large sizes.

Here is the setup.

A git master repo is here with about 900megs of files and and objects file that is 1.8g:

```
[gitmaster.local] du -hs 
2.7G    .
[gitmaster.local]$ cd .git/objects/
[gitmaster.local]$ du -hs
1.8G    .
```

I do run some maintenance on this repo to keep it clean. 
Daily I run these 2 commands in a script:

```
GIT_PROG2="/usr/bin/git-reflog expire --expire=now --all"
GIT_PROG3="/usr/bin/git-gc"
```

and weekly I run these:

```
GIT_PROG2="/usr/bin/git-reflog expire --expire=now --all"
GIT_PROG3="/usr/bin/git-repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250 -f "
```

There are a few different git client that pull from this server roughly every 15-30 minutes. 
They are pulling the exact same thing via a cron job with a simple 'git pull'. Weekly these repos do a:

```
GIT_PROG2="/usr/bin/git-reflog expire --expire=now --all"
GIT_PROG3="/usr/bin/git-gc"
```

However, occasionally, one of them will spiral out of control and fill up it's disk space with .git/objects filling up 99.9% of the space. All it's doing is a simple 'git pull'.

```
gitclient001
1.3G    .
gitclient002
1.3G    .
gitclient003
1.3G    .
gitclient004  <-- woops!
101.2G  .
gitclient005
1.3G    .
gitclient006
1.3G    .
```

My current solution when this happens is to blow it away and reclone with a depth=1. As I don't really care about the historical data so much.  I'd rather it be operational than worry about a few days of changes.

Clearly, I'd rather this run smoothly.  What might be causing this behavior to occur? Any thoughts or suggestions on where to look?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there large binary files in your repo. I wonder if git is deciding to keep copies rather than calculating deltas or big files. Have you tried a newer/different version of git as well?

Comment: No binaries, just a bunch of json and txt files. The largest file is a directory at 1.1M (not counting the json's inside it)

Comment: Damnit, had another one today.  Any help in tracking this down, or where to start much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading git - I see latest version is v1.7.12.2

Comment: Sorry it is actually v1.7.12.3

Comment: currently using 'git-1.7.4.1-1.el5'

Comment: As I recall, if a fatal error occurs during `git repack`, the temporary packfiles it was writing don't get deleted. When this happens, do you have files like `.git/objects/pack/.tmp-*`? More generally, `du -ak .git | sort -rn` may bring specific unexpected large files to your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `git fsck` and seeing if it reports anything that could explain the problem?

You could perhaps script a bit and pass the blobs to `git show <sha>1 |wc` to see if there are any big ones.